# How to tag all Facebook group members?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, javascript, facebook-tags

I'm an admin on a Facebook group, I would like to tag all group members to a post, how to do so?

Does `@group name` work? I've seen on Youtube some bot software that claims to do that, but I don't trust this program, and I'm not on Windows anyway, I'm on Linux.

I have [Tempermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) extension installed on Google chrome, is there a Javascript that can do that? I have Firefox too.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to tag a Facebook group in a post. Below are instructions:

Step 1
Log into your Facebook account and then navigate to the item you'd like to update with a tag. Click on the "Comment" hyperlink beneath a status or image posting to tag a Facebook user in the post's comments sections. To tag a group to your status, click inside of your status box at the top of your news feed.

Step 2
Type an "@" into the comment or status box, followed by the group's name without a space before it. For example, type "@soccerclub" to tag a group named "Soccer Club" to your post. Facebook will attempt to predict the group for which you're searching. Click on the group's name when it appears beneath the comment or status box.

Step 3
Click on the "Post" button to submit your status update with the desired group tagged in it. For comments, hit the "Enter" key on your keyboard to post your comment and its tag.

Comment: so by tagging the group name all the members of the group will be tagged? will they receive a notification?

Comment: By doing this you are not tagging people in the group. All they get is a notification of a post. When tagging the notification says "so and so mentioned you". This way it says "so and so posted to the group"

Comment: Amazing thank you!!!

Answer (score -2):

Sure, they would get a notification because they have been tagged on a post.
but if a member disable notification from that group,the member might not see it, unless he or she checks there profile.

Comment: What you really want to say??